# Change content assist suggestions order (move "String" above "string")

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, content-assist

I need eclipse content assist to place "java.lang.String" above types starting with "string" (see image attached). Is that possible?

[image]

Please note that it is essential for this question that "string" is typed with non-capital "s" first. There is no problem if it start with capital letter.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does it not order them based on how often you use them? E.g. if you start using java.lang.String, it'll start appearing at the top. (Just tested in my eclipse and seemed to work for me.)

Comment: I guess it weights capital-not capital leters more than frequency of use

Comment: @BenjaminDale That is very interesting, can you post screenshot here?

Comment: See answers below for screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: before and after]

I typed in "Stri" and hit ctrl + space. Then I moved down to "java.lang.String" and hit Enter. The next time I hit ctrl + space on "Stri", java.lang.String was at the top.

Comment: It's essential for my case that "string" is typed from non-capital letter "s" first.

Comment: Why? Do you lack a shift-key? I'm not sure then, I've never had to go into the config that deep before :D

Comment: It will be more convenient for me. Im used to start all types with small letters and then use code assist. It is only String that cause problems. And my guess it's only actual in Android environment since it have a lot of "string" resource types.

Comment: I did consider it being the android environment that's the issue. I tested using a plain ol' java editor environment.